# Gulp task to copy

Tags: jquery, gulp, bower

I have the following **script:**

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

var paths = {
  bower: "./bower_components/",
  scripts: "./webroot" + "/scripts/"
};

gulp.task("copy", function () {

  var bower = {
    "jquery": "jquery/jquery*.{js,map}"
  }

  for (var path in bower) {
    gulp.src(paths.bower + bower[path])
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts + path));
  }

});
```

The copy task works fine. But it does not work with:

```
"jquery": "jquery*.{js,map}"
```

or

```
"jquery": "jquery/jquery*.{js}"
```

Why can't I save the file into "scritps/" without the subfolder jQuery?

Or why can't I remove map?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, does that mean it doesn't copy anything or just not the files you're after? Can you list some sample contents of `./bower_components/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just do this, seems simpler and will do what you asked. Just replace '{js,map}' with 'js' if you dont want that file

```
var bower = './bower_components';
var dest = './webroot';

gulp.task('copy', function () {
    return gulp.src(bower + '/jquery/dist/*.{js,map}')
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + '/scripts'));
});
```